# how to reset the function?

Tags: javascript, function, reset

I have a quotes app and this is my code. the problem is when I click the button and randomly one of the three div elements appears because I set the style.display to block
now I click on generator again and I want a div appears randomly again but the previous div's display becomes none again!

```
let quotes = document.getElementsByClassName("quotes");

let btn = document.getElementById("generate");

btn.addEventListener('click',function(){
    let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3); 
    quotes[random].style.display = "block";
})
```

Comment: So remove the dispay block from all the quotes before you put it on a new one.  Better yet, use a class that is easier to find and remove

Answer (score 0):

What you will want to do is HIDE all the quotes every time you generate a new random quote. I also updated your random function so it uses the number of quote divs so it can be more dynamic for you.

```js
let quotes = document.getElementsByClassName("quotes");

let btn = document.getElementById("generate");

btn.addEventListener('click',function(){
    for(var i = 0;i<quotes.length;i++){
      quotes[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    
    let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length); 
   
    quotes[random].style.display = "block";
});
```

```css
.quotes{display:none;}
```

```html
<div class="quotes">1</div>
<div class="quotes">2</div>
<div class="quotes">3</div>
<button id="generate" type="button">Generate</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let quotes = document.getElementsByClassName("quotes");
let btn = document.getElementById("generate");

btn.addEventListener('click',function(){
    const previousQuote = document.querySelector('.quotes.show');

    if (previousQuote) previousQuote.classList.remove('show');

    const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);

    quotes[random].classList.add('show');
});
```

If you use a class, rather than inline styling, you can easily add it, and also use it to find which one you need to revert to being hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can define another class in CSS and instead of setting the randomly selected div's display to block each time, you may want to toggle the element's class. ( in order to prevent the problem) like: `quotes[random].classList.toggle("yourDesiredStyle");`